# Must employer pay extra for entire weekend of working on a holiday or just day?

Tags: canada, labor-law, british-columbia

I sometimes work Sundays. There is a holiday on Monday, it's Thanksgiving. Where I live we [get paid extra for working a holiday](http://www.bclaws.ca/Recon/document/ID/freeside/00_96113_01#section46). Should I get paid extra for working this Sunday? I'm guessing I know the answer, but other companies in the industry pay extra for the whole weekend and not just the holiday.

Comment: Are you working on the holiday or not? There's your answer. You should probably check that the extra pay is applied to only weekends prior to holidays, rather than to every weekend as an overtime.

Comment: Which days exactly are you working?

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm working Sunday. The holiday is Monday and I'm wondering if that has an affect?